# Android listview inside tabhost is not scrolling smoothly

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-tabhost

I have loaded two activities in two tabs under `TabHost` using intent. Both activities have listviews inside them. Problem is ListView is not at all scrolling smoothly. But if I make longer and faster flicks from bottom of the screen to middle then list is scrolling smoothly. Also if I load this activity separately rather than in `TabHost`, still `ListView` scrolling performance is awesome. Only inside `TabHost` it behaves slow, stuck a lot. I have already implemented Adapter, `ViewHolder`, less work in `getView()` etc to improve `ListView` performance, but the problem is not with `ListView` but `ListView` inside `TabHost`.

Comment: Just an advice - track the trace. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html It will help to understand the deeper cause.

Comment: can you post your code here.

Comment: Thanks Arturs and Abhishek
Can't share the code
Can anyone tell me what decides the scrolling speed of the list. I mean if I flick gradually it scrolls few list items and if I flick with higher speed/acceleration, many list items are scrolled. Is there any parameter by which I can manually adjust this scrolling speed.